# Github Composite action cannot find file

Tags: github-actions

I have created an action that runs the following command

```
 - name: Create Release Notes File
   env: 
    COMMITTEXT: "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
   run: |
      php ./create-release-notes-file.php
```

The file is in the same folder as the create-release.yml which is .github/workflows

when the action runs it fails with the following error:

```
Run php ./create-release-notes-file.php
Could not open input file: ./create-release-notes-file.php
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I can't find any documentation that tells me to put the files anywhere else. Any suggestions welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have cloned the repo before the above step (like with the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout)@v3), as example:

```yaml
jobs:
  create-release-note:
    name: Create Release note
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
        persist-credentials: false
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_API_TOKEN }}
    - name: Create Release Notes File
      env: 
       COMMITTEXT: "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
      run: |
       php ./create-release-notes-file.php
```